# Getting a TypeError: in python

Tags: python-3.x

I was running the code mentioned below:

```
n= 5
def fact(n):
    if n== 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return (n*fact(n-1))

print(fact(n))
```

I got the correct `output: 120`

but then 2 of the questions popped into my head:

first one is that when `n == 0` why it is not just printing `1` , it is multiplying the `return 1` with the output came from the recursion. In this case, after recalling the function itself (5*4*3*2*1) 120 comes as output. So my question is that why it is getting multiplied instead of printing `1`

My question is that when i remove `return 1` and just put `print(1)` in place, it starts giving me

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

in line 6 and 8 that is

```
return (n*fact(n-1))
```

and why that `print` error is coming in line 6 and line 8

Comment: `return 1` is not the same as `print(1)`; why would you expect `return 1` to print the 1?

Comment: Because you wrote `n*fact(n-1)`, which multiplies `n` by whatever `fact(n-1)` returns.

Comment: I don't get any error when running this and I don't see any watching your code. Are you sure that you did not make any typo somewhere?

Comment: above code is correct my friend but i'm still not getting the logic of output getting multiplied with return 1 or return whatever the number is .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> first one is that when n == 0

Which `n` ? The global one, or the function's argument ?-)

(ok, I assume you mean "the function argument")

> why it is not just printing 1

Why would it ? Where have you seen a "print()" call in your function code ?

> it is multiplying the return 1 with the output came from the recursion.

Well yes, that's what you asked it to do.

> In this case, after recalling the function itself (5*4*3*2*1) 120 comes as output. So my question is that why it is getting multiplied instead of printing 1

Because that's what you asked it to do:

```
 return (n*fact(n-1))
```

> when i remove return 1 and just put print(1) in place, it starts giving me "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'"

Of course. If you don't explicitely return a value from your function, it returns `None`. So when the recursion reaches the point where `n == 0`, your function now returns `None`.

> in line 6 and 8 that is `return (n*fact(n-1))` and why that print error is coming in line 6 and line 8

Because it's at this point that you are trying to multiply `n` with the return value of `fact(n-1)`. If at this points `n == 1`, then `fact(n-1)` is actually `fact(0)`, and you've made `fact(0)` return `None`.

Using a couple print() calls (*without* breaking the code this time) might help you visualize what's happening:
def fact(n):
    print("in fact({})".format(n))
    if n== 0:
        print("n == 0, returning 1")
        return 1
    else:
        print("n > 0, calling fact({})".format(n-1))
        res = fact(n-1)
        print("result from fact({}) is {}".format(n-1, res))
        print("returning {} * {}".format(n, res))
        return n * res

which outputs:

```
>>> fact(5)
in fact(5)
n > 0, calling fact(4)
in fact(4)
n > 0, calling fact(3)
in fact(3)
n > 0, calling fact(2)
in fact(2)
n > 0, calling fact(1)
in fact(1)
n > 0, calling fact(0)
in fact(0)
n == 0, returning 1
result from fact(0) is 1
returning 1 * 1
result from fact(1) is 1
returning 2 * 1
result from fact(2) is 2
returning 3 * 2
result from fact(3) is 6
returning 4 * 6
result from fact(4) is 24
returning 5 * 24
120
>>>
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation sir, i finally understood i was just recalling my own function.

Comment: Well, that's the basic principle of recursion, isn't it ?-)

Comment: yes, for me that was the topic for today "recursion".... still learning sir ... don't mind the mistakes.

Comment: I think we all understood that you were still in the learning process here, no problem !-)